# LINQ - UNION - remove duplicated based on a single column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, union

I have this linq query where i want to remove all the duplicates based on the column MAILADR (but keep the other columns):

```
    Dim dataObject = (From a In db.TABLE1 Select New With {
        .ID = a.BENUTZERNR,
        .MAILADR = a.EMAIL,
        .BENUTZERGRP = a.USRGRP
    }) _
    .Union(
        (From b In db.TABLE12 Select New With {
        .ID = b.ID,
        .MAILADR = b.MAILADR,
        .BENUTZERGRP = b.BENUTZERGRP 
    }) _
    )
```

Comment: What is that supposed to mean *"remove all the duplicates based on the column MAILADR (but keep the other columns)"*? Either you remove the duplicates or you keep them. You can't do both. Are you trying to group here?

Comment: I meant that I want to compare only the column MAILADR and remove all duplicate rows, even if the other rows have different values in the columns ID and BENUTZERGRP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `GroupBy`operator:

```
dataObject = dataObject.GroupBy(Function(c) c.MAILADR).Select(Function(group) group.First())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can provide a comparison method (IEqualityComparer) on the overloaded Union method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx